# What happens to uncontacted tribes after we leave?

Tags: civilization

Say we develop easy interstellar travel and most people have left the Earth for other planets and colonies. The only people who are left are the uncontacted tribes.

Would they eventually exit isolation and create new civilization? 
EDIT: Would they again exit Papau New guinea or Brazil to spread across the earth like we did thousands of years ago?

What would it look like when they encounter the relics of he previous(our) civilization?
EDIT: what would remain of our civilization(say we left at 2014) after thousands of years? like would our cities remain recognizable?

Comment: RyanP as the question stands now it's far too broad: "Write me a future history of Earthbound humanity for the next 5000 years."

Comment: Upvote for interesting premise; vote to close as too broad.

Comment: It seems harsh for me to vote to close it as too broad, while also answering it, but I did...

Comment: The revised version has two questions.  You may want to limit it to just the first one and ask the other one separately later (also, I think that similar questions to the second have been asked previously).  I also have a problem with the basic premise:  it seems extremely unlikely that civilized humanity will *all* leave Earth.  Even if transport out was free and transport back was expensive, it seems likely that only a minority would leave.  That's been the more traditional colonization model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the answer is that they would eventually spread much like the original spread of humanity.  Much of our technology is so complex that it would be entirely unusable or irrelevant to the new explorers.

Of course it would still give them a head start, since our houses, workplaces and whatnot would already be present, however the real advantage would be in agriculture.  The start of agriculture was key to the advancement of humans because we settled down in order to tend our farms, built cities and civilisations, and having gone almost nowhere in 160-260 thousand years of hunting and gathering (the first biologically -us- humans are about that old, while agriculture as we understand it isn't more than 12-14 thousand years old), we suddenly began to advance very quickly once we had permanence and agriculture.

Giving the uncontacted tribes access to our cultivated plants, our fabrics and textbooks could very well mean that what took us thousands of years to learn would take them a very short time indeed once they learnt the languages of our modern world.

The groups that refused to go may well continue to live just as normal.  While a lot of jobs wouldn't be filled, we wouldn't need so many to fill them.  I imagine that we'd group up, because it's both core to our psychology and essential in order to keep using the relics of our age, like the water treatment plants and steel foundries.  Groups that cut themselves off before would likely continue to do so largely unchanged.